# Statistics books with motivation and historical tidbits about the development of the concepts?

Tags: statistics, reference-request

I've seen some questions asking books on statistics. I'm looking something a little different, I'm specifically looking for a book in statistics that teaches the important concepts well and also speaks a little about the motivation of the concepts and the history of their development. I'm looking for something Stillwell-Like.

Comment: Certain kinds of students are intolerant of certain kinds of motivations.  For example, those who want to know how to use statistics in medicine or psychology or finance may loathe the kind of mathematical reasoning involved in explaining why root-mean-square deviation rather than mean absolute deviation. That may be one reason why many books don't have this kind of stuff. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes. And I'm looking exactly to the mathematical motivation for them. I'm curious to know exactly what made them develop the concept (be it "mathematical" or not). I marked "mathematical" because sometimes in the development of mathematics, things were not really mathematically justified, such as Leibniz infinitesimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've searched for books in the history of statistics. They're not really textbooks in statistics, but they could be used as parallel readings with a textbook.

- Annotated Readins in the History of Statistics: H.A. David; A.W.F. Edwards.
- Fitting linear relationships, A History of the Calculus of Observations 1750-1900: Richard William Farebrother.
- A History of Probability and Statistics and Their Applications before 1750: Anders Hald.
- The history of statistics, the measurement of unvertainty before 1900: Stephen M. Stigler.
- Statistics on the Table, The history of statistical concepts and methods: Stephen M. Stigler.